# C# Is there a way to get table object in excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

I'm looking for a way to retrieve some kind of table object which was created in Excel sheet and then operate on it.

I tried something like this:

```
Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

        foreach (var sheetObject in activeWorksheet.ListObjects)
        {
            if ((sheetObject as Excel.TableObject) != null)
            {
                var table = (Excel.TableObject)sheetObject;
            }

            if ((sheetObject as Excel.DataTable) != null)
            {
                var table = (Excel.DataTable)sheetObject;
            }

            if ((sheetObject as Excel.PivotTable) != null)
            {
                var table = (Excel.PivotTable)sheetObject;
            }

            if ((sheetObject as Excel.ModelTable) != null)
            {
                var table = (Excel.ModelTable)sheetObject;
            }

            if ((sheetObject as Excel.QueryTables) != null)
            {
                var table = (Excel.QueryTables)sheetObject;
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately any of this cast is returning anything else then null.
Do you know maybe some other way to retrieve such table in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work just on tables created in worksheet, I've used 'Range' as suggested in previous answer:

```
        Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

        foreach (Excel.ListObject table in activeWorksheet.ListObjects)
        {
            Excel.Range tableRange = table.Range;
            String[] dataInRows = new string[tableRange.Rows.Count];

            int i = 0;

            foreach (Excel.Range row in tableRange.Rows)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < row.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[1, j + 1].Value2 != null)
                    {
                        dataInRows[i] = dataInRows[i] + "_" + row.Cells[1, j + 1].Value2.ToString();
                    }
                }

                i++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Range?

from: http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel

```
Range excelRange = sheet.UsedRange;
object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(
    XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_members(v=vs.15).aspx

Comment: I would like to focus not on a whole worksheet, but just on a tables in this sheet. But indication of Range helped me very much in finding a solution, thanks